# jQuery autocomplete for dynamically created inputs for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-1.7

I'm having an issue using jQuery autocomplete with dynamically created inputs (again created with jQuery). I can't get autocomplete to bind to the new inputs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.count = 0;
        if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};

        var autocomp_opt = {
                width: 300,
                max: 10,
                delay: 100,
                minLength: 1,
                autoFocus: true,
                cacheLength: 1,
                scroll: true,
                highlight: false,
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/test/JSON/PACS8Data",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: request,
                        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log( data);
                            var items = data;
                            response(items);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                             console.log( textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
            };



            function addme () {
                window.count++;
                var text = $( "#hiddenDiv" ).html();

                text = replaceAll("XXYY", ""+window.count, text);
                $( "#appendText" ).append(text);
                $('.description', text).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);

            }

            function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
                  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
            }


    </script>


        <br />

        <div id="jsftextAjax" >
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="autoText0" class="description" maxlength="20" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="valueText0" maxlength="20" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="add0" type="button" onclick="addme();">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="appendText">

        </div>
        <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="autoTextXXYY" class="description" maxlength="20" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="valueTextXXYY" maxlength="20" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="addXXYY" type="button" onclick="addme();">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I'm aware that the problem is due to the content being created after the page has been loaded but I can't figure out how to get around it. I've read several related questions and come across the jQuery live method but I'm still in a jam!

Any advice?

Comment: why `$('.description', text)` : text is invalid here. Remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693758/how-do-you-bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following snippet,

Remove `text` from `$('.description').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);`

```
function addme () {
    window.count++;
    var text = $( "#hiddenDiv" ).html();

    text = replaceAll("XXYY", ""+window.count, text);
    $( "#appendText" ).append(text);
    $('.description').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);

}
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdHwh)**

**Note :**

The `autocomplete()` code won't work for 1st set of textbox. for that include `$('.description').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);` in your `$(document).ready(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.description', text).autocomplete(autocomp_opt); <-- You are looking at a string text as the context
```

You need to work of the elements that were added.

```
$( "#appendText" )
    .append(text)
    .find('.description')
        .autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
```

or

```
var elems = $(text);
$( "#appendText" ).append(elems);
elems.find('.description').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
```

Comment: Thanks friend epascarello