# Autocomplete to inputs added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm have an autocomplete function in JQUERY and a function that add an input in javascript.The problems is when I add the input, the autocomplete function doesn't work for it.

This is my autocomplete function in jquery:

```
$(function() {
$(".espaciado").autocomplete({

  source:"/inicio/api/get_asesores/",

  function (event, ui) { //item selected

    AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui);

  },
  minLength: 1,
    });
 });

  function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
 {
   var selectedObj = ui.item;
 }
```

This is my javacript function with which I add the input

```
  var id= 2   
  function AgregarAsesor(clicked_id) {
    var td = document.getElementById('scrollbar')

    var asesorID = "asesor_" + id;
    var cell=document.createElement("div");
    cell.id = id;
    adviserText = document.createElement("input");
    adviserText.setAttribute("type","text");
    adviserText.setAttribute('class', "ui-widget espaciado");
    adviserText.setAttribute('id',asesorID);
    var addadviser=document.createElement("i");  
    addadviser.id ="añadir_"+id;
    addadviser.setAttribute("onclick","AgregarAsesor('"+id+"')");
   addadviser.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-plus espacio');
   cell.appendChild(adviserText);
   cell.appendChild(addadviser);
   td.appendChild(cell);
   id = id + 1;
```

};

and this is who the autocomplete is in the input that alredy exists

```
<input type"text" class="ui-widget  espaciado" id="adviser_1"> <i id="añadir_1" class="fa fa-plus espacio" aria-hidden='true' onclick="AgregarAsesor(this.id)"></i>
```

How Can I do to add the autocomplete function to the dinamically added inputs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .on()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693758/how-do-you-bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-on)

Comment: I change my autocomplete function, and know it doesn't works